# GPIO TXD0 vs RXD0 vs SDA1 vs SCL1

Tags: gpio

Looking on the below Raspberry Pi scheme I notice that there are different kinds of GPIO pins (TXD0, RXD0, GPIO_GEN1 etc.)

What is the difference between them?

[image: GPIO pinout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the GPIO may be used as inputs or outputs.  They are called modes, the GPIO is in input mode or in output mode.

In addition some GPIO may be configured to be in other useful modes.

[BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) page 102 shows the modes that individual GPIO may use.  Unless you have a compute module only GPIO 0 to 27 are of any interest.

In TXD/RXD mode the GPIO may be used as a serial link (many devices can communicate via a serial link).

In I2C mode the GPIO may be used to implement an I2C bus (many sensors, e.g. RTC (Real Time Clock), can communicate via I2C).

In SPI mode the GPIO may be used to implement a SPI bus (many sensors, e.g. ADC (Analog Digital Converter), can communicate via SPI).

Other potentially useful modes are CLK (for generating a clock signal) and PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) for setting motor speed, driving servos, dimming LEDs etc.

Answer (score 1):

[pinout.xyz](http://pinout.xyz) has a nice gizmo for exploring Pi pins. An example from their descriptions:

BCM14/TXD:

> This pin doubles up as the UART transmit pin, TXD. It's also commonly
>   known as "Serial" and, by default, will output a Console from your Pi
>   that, with a suitable Serial cable, you can use to control your Pi via
>   the command-line.
>
> Thus, The UART pins are useful for setting up a "headless" Pi (a Pi
>   without a screen) and getting it connected to a network.
>
> UART can also be extremely useful if you want to talk to Arduino or
>   Propeller boards from your Pi, but you must make sure you disable the
>   Serial Console in raspi-config first.

Pins labelled as 'GPIO_GEN[x]' are, I believe, just GENeral purpose I/O pins with no special associated functions.